# VCS System that preserves Unix file permissions?

Tags: linux, unix, git, revision-control

I'm looking for a simple revision control system for server configs. Something like works like git, but preserves Unix file permissions. And is NOT RCS.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the characteristics of RCS you need to be absent in the not-RCS tool?

Comment: why not just write a small bash script that logs /restores the permissions on each versioned file, and check that into the vcs also ? Generally i think the reason most systems dont do it automatically is because its alot more hassle than its worth with regards to file ownership and checkouts going to more than one client.

Comment: A configuration management system ([Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) or similar) can effectively do revision control on your configuration files, and can also set permissions after installing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at etckeeper

It does well with /etc perms, and can be extended to work outside /etc.

Also git by itself, can be extended with hooks:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html